# CometD receiving published data using jquery in front-end

Tags: javascript, jquery, comet, datatables, cometd

I'm doing a market/stocks watch web project.

At the server side I have a Servlet and Service on a cometd-jetty implementation.

The Service (CometD Client publisher) sends a JSON published data. i.e. [{"Stock Code":"ABC"},{"Stock Code":"DEF"}]. Time interval of published data is almost every second or even less.

At Front-end, I'm using cometd javascript implementation to fetch the data and render it in html table using jquery.

Questions:

1.) What is the best way to render the data in a table (using datatables plugin) with very fast receiving of data from publisher/cometd server (less than a second each message)?

2.) How can I indicate change in price through **hi-lighting** table cell when stock price changes? I'm trying to figure this out using js or jquery?

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1) The DataTables plugin can use a JavaScript array as its data source. You'll have some sort of method that's processing incoming data; push that into a JS array and then call .dataTable() with that as your source.

2) Inside the DataTables initialization object you can set callback functions at various stages. One of these is fnRowCallback, which allows you to modify the row and the cells within, based on the available data. Grab the data, run your comparison function, and when the conditions are met, modify the cell.

For both questions, there should be sample code available at DataTables.net.

Comment: As per 1st answer I've already done that. The second one, my understanding in what you said is that I can get the previous and the new cell value. Is that right? If that's the case I can implement the desired hi-lighting feature. Thanks for the answer Greg!

Comment: Hm, I gave the wrong impression I think. By the time the fnRowCallback is triggered, the previous value is gone. You will run the comparison function from within fnRowCallback, but the "previous" data needs to be available somewhere else. Each time the data comes into DataTables, you should store a copy of it in a properly-scoped variable.